# chrome BORDER not rounding with border RADIUS

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a image

```
<img class="user-img" src="user_img/usr.jpg" alt="username" />
```

and adding a radius of 100px to create a circle.

```
.user-img {
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 100px ;
  border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px 0px #999999; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px 0px #999999; /* Safari, Chrome */
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px 0px #999999; /* CSS3 */
}
```

and this works fine, but then I add

```
  border: solid 7px white;
```

This works in FF but in Chrome the border does not follow the radius of the rounded img.

Here's a demo http://jsfiddle.net/afro360/zcQ3G/2/

Suggestions anyone?

Thanks

Comment: Did you view the demo using Chrome?

Comment: Chrome 21.0.1180.79 in mac OS X Lion 10.7.4

Comment: linked to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240667/css3-border-radius-inside-is-square-on-chrome-safari (make the radius less to see the effect)

Comment: Chrome 18.0.1025.168 in Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Please see my above comment:)